# Uneven readings for tire pressure

Tags: tires, winter, acura, tire-pressure

I'm new to this community so please instruct me if the question needs improving.

On an Acura 2010 TL SH-4WD, is the following reading normal regarding the tire pressure?

[image]

The tires are winter tires that were very recently put on by a dealership. What are the normal, average, bad ranges for these pressure numbers?

Should I be worried that the rear right tire always had a higher reading than the rear left and the 2 front tires? Driving was during 5 degree Celcius (real feel 0) and on a city road. The trunk was carrying a heavy load (the all-season tires) with the center of mass skewed to the right.

Comment: Great question! Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 4):

Well, there's a few things going on here:

- your tire pressure monitoring system is saying the pressures are OK (first line at the top)
- the units for these numbers are kiloPascals (kPa, right next to your front-right tire pressure)
- ideally, tire pressures should be even, but we don't live in an ideal world. The variation you have isn't huge.
- if you prefer PSI for units, check your owner's manual, I'm sure there's a procedure to follow to switch units (same with temperature units)
- for the normal range, each car has it's own specs. There's a sticker somewhere on your car that tells you what the normal pressures are for your car. Look either on the pillar between the driver door and the rear door when your driver door is open, or on the vertical edge of the driver door where it latches with said pillar, or inside the glove box. You should aim to keep your tires as close to the recommended pressures as possible.
- regarding your right rear being higher, maybe it was inflated with a bit more air to begin with. Once you find what your recommended pressures are, you can stop at an air station and adjust all 4 pressures to match.
- regarding the outside temperature, do keep in mind that tires lose pressure when they get cold and they gain pressure when they get hot. You should adjust your tire pressures when the outside temperature is "normal" for that time of the year.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll print out your answer and go check tomorrow morning. If there aren't further issue, I'll accept and close the question. The answer is informative and is helpful for a newbie like me. I really appreciate it.